# How to call .Net Web Services in Android Application Using Eclipse

Tags: .net, android, web-services

Am new in Android Application how to call .Net WebServices in Android am implementing
my code is please check

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
     tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    call();
}
public void call()
{
    try {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("hello", "world");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug=true;

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

      // SoapPrimitive sp=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

     Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();

        tv.setText(result.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        tv.setText(e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

But am getting Error Delimiter missing,also operation timeout and anyone please help me how to debug Android application using Eclipse

Thanks
@Lakshmi

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform any network operations on the UI thread or your Android will generate an ANR Error Dialog. Place your network code inside an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to avoid and ANR error.

Note without seeing the logcat output I can not be sure this is the error you are having.